how to make jinja2 remove newlines/spaces generated by tags but preserve newlines/spaces generated by static text
When using a jinja2 template such as this
A
{%- if flag == "0" %}
X
{%- elif flag == "1" %}
Y
{%- endif %}
B

my intuitive goal would be, whatever A,B,X,Y are, to simply "insert the contents X,Y between A,B".
This means I'd expect for flag=0,1,2 the following results:
A
X
B

A
Y
B

A
B

Note that A,B,X,Y are not jinja2 variables, they are placeholders for static text in the template, which, however,
could also consist of multiple lines.
I seek for a general syntax which satisfies my above expectation for any A,X,Y,B,
i.e. if I edit the contents of the fields A,X,Y,B I do not want to touch the syntax.
The syntax given above does not fulfill this requirement, if the fields A,B,X,Y have newlines in their surrounding,
e.g. if I change it to
a
{%- if flag == "0" %}
x
{%- elif flag == "1" %}
  y
 y

{%- endif %}
b

(now a,b,x,y are real characters, placeholder Y has multiple lines and ends with an empty line)
it will produce for flag=1 the output
a
  y
 y
b

while according to my expectation I want this output
a
  y
 y

b

As I work with a newline-senstive target-language, I would now have to adopt the template syntax again.
So I seek a general template syntax of the following form
A
{????}
X
{????}
Y
{????}
B

which works for any placeholders A,B,X,Y. In this form, jinja2 tags and target placeholders are required to be on separate lines.
What I tried so far:
Playing with my initial template (switching 6 minus signs and adding some newlines at 4 positions) I generated 2^10 = 1024 possible templates.
10 of them only work for A,B,X,Y without newlines, with newlines, none of them does.
The problem seems to be, that using {%- syntax after Y removes the newline before the { (wanted) but at the same time removes the trailing spaces of Y (not wanted)
Considering the question title, I know that it is not clearly distinguishable if a newline is "caused" by a tag or static text, but this was the best I could come up with.


I want jinja2 syntax and target language code on separate lines is

Use lstrip_blocks=true, trim_blocks=true options.
Without them, it is not possible. Patch jinja2 or use something else.

That would be:
A
{% if flag == "0" %}X
{% elif flag == "1" %}Y
{% endif %}B

and:
a
{% if flag == "0" %}x
{% elif flag == "1" %}  y
 y

{% endif %}b

I sometimes do:
a
{% if flag == "0" 
%}x
{% elif flag == "1" 
%}  y
 y

{% endif 
%}b

Bottom line you are searching for lstrip_blocks=true, trim_blocks=true jinja2 template options.

Thanks, but in Your solution jinja2 tags and target language code appear on the same line. I tried to exclude answers of this type (see my syntax pattern with the {{????}} in my question). I improved the question to make this more obvious. The reason why I want jinja2 syntax and target language code on separate lines is, it decreases cognitive load for people who work with the templates.

Sorry, I don't fully understand how Your "bottom line" is related to the rest of Your answer, do You say Your syntax examples only work with these options, or these options are another equivalent solution?

these options are another equivalent solution? this

That works, thank You. I was only using jinja2-cli which seemingly does not let me set these options, but using these options from within python does.

Yes, so upvote https://github.com/mattrobenolt/jinja2-cli/pull/126 and https://github.com/mattrobenolt/jinja2-cli/issues/124
